# Transition высоты контейнера или последующего элемента

Tags: css, фильтры, transition, height

Доброго времени суток.

Есть моя реализация фильтрации отображаемых элементов на бутстрапе `(.col {float:left;})`. Основа на css, изменение классов на jquery.

Все красиво работает с помощью изменения ширины скрываемых элементов, но есть один нюанс. Последующий элемент после контейнера, а равно и высота контейнера, не реагирует на `transition`.

Как можно это победить? Желательно на css

Пример "нереагируемости" здесь: https://jsfiddle.net/1vyxgmut/4/

Голый фиддл для ваших примеров здесь: https://jsfiddle.net/1vyxgmut/3/

Comment: Я не вижу, чтобы вы как-то взаимодействовали с контейнером `.example-box` в скрипте или css. Если в консоли добавить класс `.hidden-partner` этому блоку - transition работает. Ну и после контейнера у вас непарный закрывающий тег div

Comment: Непарный тег по ошибке был добавлен. Сейчас исправлю.
Так суть не совсем во взаимодействии, суть в плавном увеличении высоты/смещении при изменении содержимого контейнера.